# Cisco AMP API python script

Tags: python, json, python-requests, cisco

I'm trying to write a script to pull the events from our Cisco AMP environment using the cisco api and Python. below is  what I started with but I'm getting a file not found error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'request.json'"

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://<your_client_id>:<your_api_key>@api.amp.sourcefire.com/v1/events'
payload = open("request.json")
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print (json.dumps(response))
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Wait, just realized the error is in `payload = open("request.json")`. Why are you trying to open `request.json`?

Comment: Can you put that in code blocks in your question?

Comment: the curl script looks like: `curl -X GET -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'content-type: application/json' --compressed -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -u b7014a3aa062a91cb67e:<password> 'api.amp.cisco.com/v1/events' -o "ciscoamp_eventsAPI.txt" `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your code is working right...

```
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print (json.dumps(response.text))
```

You could also try just this

```
print(response.json())
```

Comment: same error, I'm not sure about the correct use of the payload section. I put the working curl script above but I'm not exactly sure how to do this in python.